# Вызов функции с Server на Client в домашней сети интернета

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, visual-studio, localhost

Хотел бы реализовать программу на  Visual Studio (Windows Form), в двух экземплярах. Одно приложение было бы сервером, другое клиентом.

Допустим клиент это просто процесс, без какого либо визуального управления (кнопок, картинок и прочего), а сервер с одной единственной кнопкой (отправить).
Нужно сделать так, чтобы когда сервер нажимал на кнопку отправить, то у клиента открывалось окно с картинкой, или издавался звук, в общем просто вызывалась любая функция.
В данном случае все MAC адреса и IP я знаю, так как программа нужна сугубо в домашней сети (localhost), меняются только устройства.

Comment: [Network programming in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/networking/overview). И там смотрите сокеты, TCP и прочее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопорс достаточно общий, поэтому в деталях с теорией:

0. Для Windows Form используйте соединение между сервером и клиентом через сокеты.
1. На серверной стороне создайте экземпляр класса Socket и используйте его для прослушивания входящих соединений.
2. Когда клиент подключится, создавайте новый экземпляр класса Socket для общения с ним.
3. Чтобы клиенту сообщить о том, что нужно открыть окно с картинкой или воспроизвести звук, серверу необходимо отправить сообщение, например, в формате JSON:

```
{"action": "show_image"} 
{"action": "play_sound"}
```

4. Клиент должен всегда прослушивать входящие соединения от сервера и обрабатывать сообщения. В ответ на команды вызывать нужные методы.
5. Чтобы отправить сообщение, используйте метод Send класса Socket. Чтобы принять сообщение, используйте метод Receive класса Socket.

[Раздел с рекомендациями и примерами](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/networking/sockets/socket-services?source=recommendations)

[Прослушивание сокетов](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/networking/sockets/tcp-classes)

Comment: Благодарю, буду копать в эту сторону 